# SQL Pivot - adding another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I think what I need here is to create a pivot table.  I can do it without having the laborhours column, but when I try to create it with the laborhours column it doesn't work.

Would you please show me how to get the results I am asking for?

There are multiple more "Par" values, which are not shown below.

Here is my table:

```
WorkDate    Par QTY laborhrs
03/14/14    CR  100 0.67
03/25/14    ET  100 0.73
03/05/14    CR  50  0.37
03/13/14    ER  50  0.72
03/04/14    YD  400 1.68
03/25/14    CR  200 0.8
03/25/14    CR  300 1.5
```

Here is what I would like:

```
WorkDate    CR  CRHours ER  ERHours ET  ETHours YD  YDHours
03/04/14    0   0       0   0       0   0       400 1.68
03/05/14    50  0.37    0   0       0   0       0   0
03/13/14    0   0       50  0.72    0   0       0   0
03/14/14    100 0.67    0   0       0   0       0   0
03/25/14    500 2.3     0   0       100 0.73    0   0
```

The new "Hours" columns are from the laborhrs column per each "par"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple approaches
You could create two PIVOT Subqueries and join them but I prefer this way

```
SELECT
t.WorkDate
,SUM(CASE WHEN t.Par='CR' THEN t.Qty ELSE 0 END) AS CR
,SUM(CASE WHEN t.Par='CR' THEN t.laborhrs ELSE 0 END) AS CRHours

,SUM(CASE WHEN t.Par='ER' THEN t.Qty ELSE 0 END) AS ER
,SUM(CASE WHEN t.Par='ER' THEN t.laborhrs ELSE 0 END) AS ERHours

,SUM(CASE WHEN t.Par='ET' THEN t.Qty ELSE 0 END) AS ET
,SUM(CASE WHEN t.Par='ET' THEN t.laborhrs ELSE 0 END) AS ETHours

,SUM(CASE WHEN t.Par='YD' THEN t.Qty ELSE 0 END) AS YD
,SUM(CASE WHEN t.Par='YD' THEN t.laborhrs ELSE 0 END) AS YDHours

GROUP BY t.WorkDate
FROM [tablename] t
```

It's the fastest approach to these problems that I've found as it just needs to traverse the table once.

Comment: Tom beat me to it. Kevin, I'm guessing that based on the fact that you said "There are multiple more "Par" values" you're insinuating that you'd rather not hardcode columns for each Par type. However, I don't think Pivot can accomplish what you're looking for, which, as far as I know, leaves you with either hardcoding the fields or writing a dynamic SQL script. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

another option is correlated queries:

```
select workdate,
(select sum(qty) from labour a where a.workdate=b.workdate and a.par='CR') CR,
(select sum(laborhrs) from labour a where a.workdate=b.workdate and a.par='CR') CRhours,
(select sum(qty) from labour a where a.workdate=b.workdate and a.par='ER') ER,
(select sum(laborhrs) from labour a where a.workdate=b.workdate and a.par='ER') ERhours,
(select sum(qty) from labour a where a.workdate=b.workdate and a.par='ET') ET,
(select sum(laborhrs) from labour a where a.workdate=b.workdate and a.par='ET') EThours,
(select sum(qty) from labour a where a.workdate=b.workdate and a.par='YD') YD,
(select sum(laborhrs) from labour a where a.workdate=b.workdate and a.par='YD') YDhours
from yourtable b
group by workdate
```

Comment: correlated subqueries are best avoided if possible. 
Think it through...
Once you've got several days data this is going to be problematic because each of those 8 correlated queries are going to have to be evaluated for each workdate value. so after a month when you've got 20 working days that's going to be 160 separate queries being evaluated just to get your 20 result rows.
That number is actually going to be bigger as there are more than 4 [par] values and it's going to keep growing

Comment: There is no reason to vote it down though. It's a valid solution to the problem; and unless the volumes are very high, the execution time will be marginal.